# Is there a way to recalculate the average at every message with Kafka-Stream?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, statistics, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to do statistics over a **cycle** of **Kafka** messages composed by a feature. I would like to recalculate the **Kurtosis** of this feature when I receive a new message of the same Cycle.

[image]

I am currently able to perform simple aggregations (additions, counts) over each message streamed.

```scala
  //set message count as new key (instead of String null)
  val newStream : KStream[Int, Message] = builder.stream[String, Message]("queueing.sensors.data" )(consumed).map((_,v) => (v.msg_count,v))

  //stream ->  ktable
  newStream.to("Dummy-ReduceInputTopic")(produced2)
  val cycleTable : KTable[Int, Message] = builder.table("Dummy-ReduceInputTopic")

  //aggregate values
  val cycleTable2 : KTable[Int, Seq[Message]] = cycleTable
    .groupBy((k, v) => (v.cycle,v))(serializedFromSerde(intSerde,messageSerde))
    .aggregate[Seq[Message]](Seq[Message]())((aggkey,newvalue,aggvalue) => aggvalue :+ newvalue, (aggkey,newvalue,aggvalue) => aggvalue)(materializedFromSerde(intSerde,seqmesageSerde))

  //create messageList objects => apply predictions
  val cycleTable3 : KStream[Int, Double] = cycleTable2.toStream.map((k,v) => (k,MessageList(v.toSeq).skewness_ps1))
```

Is there something in Kafka equivalent to **Spark Streaming Sliding Windows** ?

Should I give up Kafka Stream for this use case ? For Spark Streaming ?

I thank you in advance for paying attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kafka you also have the Windowing concept:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#windowing

Some examples here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Stream+Usage+Patterns#KafkaStreamUsagePatterns-Howtocomputean(windowed)average?

Example Kafka Stream

```
KTable<Windowed<Key>, Value> fifteenMinuteWindowed = 

    fiveMinuteWindowed

    .groupBy( (windowedKey, value) -> 
        new KeyValue<>(
            new Windowed<>(
                windowedKey.key(),
                new Window<>(
                    windowedKey.window().start() /1000/60/15 *1000*60*15,
                    windowedKey.window().start() /1000/60/15 *1000*60*15 + 1000*60*15
                    // the above rounds time down to a timestamp divisible by 15 minutes
                )
            ),
            value
        ),
        /* your key serde */, 
        /* your value serde */
    )
    .reduce(/*your adder*/, /*your subtractor*/, "store15m");
```

You could also consider **KSQL** which has the concepts:

**Hopping Window**  Time-based  Fixed-duration, overlapping windows

**Tumbling Window** Time-based Fixed-duration, non-overlapping, gap-less windows

**Session Window**  Session-based Dynamically-sized, non-overlapping, data-driven windows

Example KSQL:

```
SELECT regionid, COUNT(*) FROM pageviews
  WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 30 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS)
  WHERE UCASE(gender)='FEMALE' AND LCASE (regionid) LIKE '%_6'
  GROUP BY regionid;
```